# Rails: making a table from a collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using the Forem blogging gem. It renders the posts of a particular topic this way.

```
<%= render :partial => "forem/posts/post", :collection => @posts %>
```

Is there a way to make the output appear in a table? I've put `<td>` markup around the sections in the partial below that I want to break up into a table.

The row names I would want are Name, Posted At, Message, In Reply to, and Actions.

I thought I might be able to do something like

```
@posts.each do |p|

<tr>
p
</tr>
```

but I can't figure out how to get it to work

Partial

```
<a name='post-<%= post.id %>'></a>
<div id='post_<%= post.id %>' class='post <%= cycle('odd', 'even') -%>'>


  <td>
      Name:<%= link_to_if Forem.user_profile_links, post.user, [main_app, post.user] %>
    </div>
    <div class='icon'><%#= avatar(post.user, :size => 60) %></div>

  </td>



 <td>
    <a href='#post-<%= post.id %>'>
      <time datetime="<%= post.created_at.to_s(:db) -%>"><%= "#{time_ago_in_words(post.created_at)} #{t("ago")}" %></time>
    </a>
 </td>
 <td>
    <%= forem_format(post.text) %>
 </td>

<td>
    <% if post.reply_to %>
      <span class='in_reply_to'>
        <%= link_to "#{t("forem.post.in_reply_to")} #{post.reply_to.user}", "#post-#{post.reply_to.id}" %>
      </span>
    <% end %>
</td>

<td>

    <ul class='actions'>
      <% if forem_user %>
        <% if can?(:reply, @topic) %>
          <% if @topic.can_be_replied_to? %>
            <li><%= link_to t('reply', :scope => 'forem.topic'), new_topic_post_path(@topic, :reply_to_id => post.id) %></li>
          <% end %>
          <% if @topic.can_be_replied_to? %>
            <li><%= link_to t('quote', :scope => 'forem.topic'), new_topic_post_path(@topic, :reply_to_id => post.id, :quote => true) %></li>
          <% end %>
        <% end %>
        <% if post.owner_or_admin?(forem_user) %>
          <% if can?(:edit_post, @topic.forum) %>
            <li><%= link_to t('edit', :scope => 'forem.post'), edit_topic_post_path(@topic, post) %></li>
          <% end %>
          <li><%= link_to t('delete', :scope => 'forem.topic'), topic_post_path(@topic, post), :method => :delete, :confirm => t("are_you_sure") %></li>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
    </ul>

 </td>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What does the output look like right now?

Comment: The forum comes with different classes around various sections of this partial, but I removed them because they were a headache to style with my limited skills. That's why I wanted to use a table and I only put the 'td' tags in the partial in the OP to show generally how I wanted the table to be organized. I thought I might be able to do something like @posts.each do <td>...

Comment: What I meant was, can you share the before/after screenshots for us to take a look?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding  instead of  at the very beginning of the  code for the partial? And perhaps a  before the loop over posts?